# Disable HTML elements

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

How do I disable page?

I have a following code written using scriptaculous/prototype. It just moves a div to the center (actually at 100,100). I want the entire background (all elements) to be disabled except this div.

```
new Effect.Move(element, {x:100,y:100,duration:1});
```

Comment: What does it mean "disabled"? Form elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest covering the rest of your elements in a div and then using the z-index to move your centering div on top. Similar to below.

```
#disableElements{  
 display:none;  
 position:fixed;  
 height:100%;  
 width:100%;  
 top:0;  
 left:0;  
}
```